# Filling first concrete floor with Autoclaved aerated concrete (AAC) brick to 3 feet height is good?

Tags: concrete, floor, joists, brick, structural

First concrete floor is with 500 sq.ft. area. Out of this, 200 sq.ft. is in projected form for about 3 feet height. So, we are planning to fill in with AAC blocks up to 3 feet height for the rest of the space of 300 sq.ft. area to make up even level of the floor.

This is good idea to do so? will the building suffer with load even though we fill it with light weight AAC bircks and cause any problem in future?

Any quick suggestion is highly appreciated as we are under construction, we may manage to alter in case of any corrections needed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you really going to take the advice of some stranger on the internet who tells you that there is no danger to your building? ... hire a structural engineer

Comment: usually raised sections are constructed using wood or metal framing,  it makes for more easy installation and maintenance of underfloor services.

Comment: This seems very expensive. Framing should be a much cheaper solution...

Comment: @jsotola, Jasen, bobflux thanks for the reply. I need ideas from structural design aspect to calculate the wieght load factors to better understand the building durability in future

Comment: Does your contractor's brother own a brick company or something? Back fill with dirt, after you drill holes for rebar. It's concrete, not rocket science. Is it going to crack there anyway: probably. Bust the upper slab up, throw it in the hole with some dirt and do a continuous pour. Even then it still might crack.